# How do I create a user form that can set the variables in an SQL query before executing it?

Tags: sql, ms-access, userform

I have data that is entered on an ongoing basis in SharePoint; this table is linked in MS Access and, once a month, I *freeze* the data by copying it from the live SharePoint database into a static Access database.   I do this using a SQL query, and it works well.

Here is the gist of the query (I simplified it and removed fields for this example):

```
INSERT INTO [CALL DATA] ( FiscalMonth, FiscalYear, EncDateTime, TimeDuration )
SELECT "07-Apr" AS FiscalMonth, "FY13" AS FiscalYear, 
CallAttempts.[Attempt Date & Time], CallAttempts.[Attempt Duration (Mins)]
FROM CallAttempts
WHERE ((CallAttempts.[Attempt Date & Time]>#4/1/2013#) AND 
       (CallAttempts.[Attempt Date & Time]<#5/1/2013#) AND 
       (CallAttempts.[Attempt Duration (Mins)] IS NOT NULL));
```

As you can see, every month, I have to manually update parts of this query: values for `FiscalMonth` and `FiscalYear` and well as the date and time constraints.  This works fine for me (I coded it) but I have to turn it over to non-technical people.

I am not that versed in Access - **can I create a userform that would update this query before it executes (I'm thinking to add drop-down selections and a data picker for execution)?**  Is that even possible?

Or is there a better way to go about this altogether?

Comment: You can implement a user form with an event handler that does precisely that.  Despite this being 2013, Access event handlers are still written in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).  It's dated, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can very easily. This should get you started:

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
   Dim Mo As Integer
   Dim Yr As Integer
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim Mon As String
   Dim DateStart As Date
   Dim DateEnd As Date

   strSQL = ""
   strSQL = strSQL & "INSERT INTO [call data] " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "            (fiscalmonth, " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "             fiscalyear, " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "             encdatetime, " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "             timeduration) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT '07-@Mon' AS FiscalMonth, " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "       'fy@yr'   AS FiscalYear, " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "       callattempts.[attempt date & time], " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "       callattempts.[attempt duration (mins)] " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "FROM   callattempts " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE  ( ( callattempts.[attempt date & time] >= #@DateStart# ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "         AND ( callattempts.[attempt date & time] <#@DateEnd# ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "         AND ( callattempts.[attempt duration (mins)] IS NOT NULL ) )"

   Mo = Me.cboMonth.Value
   Yr = Me.cboYear.Value
   Mon = MonthName(Mo, True)
   DateStart = DateSerial(Yr, Mo, 1)
   DateEnd = DateAdd("m", 1, DateStart)
   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@mon", Mon)
   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@Yr", Yr)
   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@DateStart", DateStart)
   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@DateEnd", DateEnd)

   'Debug.Print strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't even have to test that to know that it's going to do what I want.  Thanks so much!  Will get to work on it!  A Google search will get me to executing that `strSQL` I'm sure.